# How to solve this issue "chip enable program error"

Tags: c, runtime-error, microprocessors

We are using [progisp software](http://prog3.com/sbdm/download/tag/PROGISP) to program a microcontroller [AT89S52](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/at89s52). We are struggeling with an issue saying

> chip enable program error

Please help us to tackle this issue? What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I polished the typesetting for you. Please add some more information, what you have tried so far, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance. In the current form, you risk that your question will be immediately closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a software programming issue.  It's about how to use particular programming utilities to operate with specific microcontroller hardware.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2019/03/30/usbasp-solution-to-chip-enable-error-firmware-upgrade/ it might just be a physical connectivity issue (or the wrong chip:

> CHIP ENABLE error occurs if the IC is not placed correctly on ZIF socket of development board or if the wrong Chip is selected.

Comment: Ok, too bad. (You can have written that in your question :-) I am sorry, that is really not my field.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked all the things which are described in this documentation https://www.academia.edu/8278452/How_to_solve_chip_enable_program_error_in_progisp?

> 1. Check if the
>      USBasp
>      driver is properly installed (update it from settings).
> 2. Recheck the jumpers. Change them if they are weakly connected.
> 3. Try to change the port, sometimes some ports can malfunction (ex. from port 1 to port 0).
> 4. Press reset button for 10 seconds.
> 5. Try to erase current program from
>      progisp
>      compiler, and load flash of hex file again

---

Or here: http://www.mbeddedc.com/2015/03/how-to-solve-chip-enable-error-in.html

> Reason for Chip enable error in progisp:
>
> 1) Main reason for this error could be wrong connections.
>    This can be solved by checking the connection between Serial ISP Programmer and Micro-controller. Many times Gnd,Vcc,Sck,MISO,MOSI,RST connection does not match with each other. This should be given properly by Gnd-Gnd, Vcc-Vcc, Sck-Sck, MISO-MISO, MOSI-MOSI, RST-RST.
>
> 2) Check whether the power to the ISP Programmer and micro-controller are correctly supplied.

It pretends to solve the issue.